# Output with startsWith method and substring unclear

Tags: java, methods, substring

I am having trouble understanding this code.The part that confuses me is the output,particularly the 3 and 5 print statemnt.How can the 3rd one be true and the 5th one false.The way I understood substrings is that it "operates" with the values after the index. Hence here it still prints out true for "This" although it should be index 0,and false for "the text". Why is that so?

```java
public class test {
    private static final String TEXT = "This is the text to be searched";

    private static boolean hasSubstring(String toFind, String findFrom) {
        if (findFrom.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (findFrom.startsWith(toFind)) {
            return true;

        }
        return hasSubstring(toFind, findFrom.substring(1));
    }


    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println(hasSubstring("text to", TEXT));
        System.out.println(hasSubstring("goo", TEXT));
        System.out.println(hasSubstring("This", TEXT));
        System.out.println(hasSubstring("searched", TEXT));
        System.out.println(hasSubstring("the  text", TEXT));
    }
}
```

Comment: A substring is a string that is contiguous part of the searched string. Not sure what index you are referring to. `This` is a part of your string. `The  text` (with two spaces) isn't.

Comment: What I meant by index is this. Every word and white space in String text has an value(index) starting from 0. So this is 0 the white space is 1 and so on.(At least that is what I think it should be). Now if we say substring(1) what should be searched is everything from that point in the string (in this case the white space). This is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah. No. Each *character* has its index, not each word. So "T" is at index 0, "h" is at index 1 etc. But you skipped over the second `if` in your program, which says that if the string starts with the required text, it immediately returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle defn,

String - subString

```
public String substring​(int beginIndex)
```

Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring **begins with the character at the specified index** and extends to the end of this string.
Examples:

"unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"

"Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"

"emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)

Parameters:
beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.

Returns:
the specified substring.

Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring

Hence part 3 is True as expected

Answer (score 0):

You have double space in the 5th test text

```
System.out.println( hasSubstring ("the  text", TEXT ));
```

Update that to single space as you mentioned above, it will work fine as you expected.

```
System.out.println( hasSubstring ("the text", TEXT ));
```

Outputs following for me with updated text:

```
true
false
true
true
true
```

Comment: Okay, but why is also the 3rd staement true? Shouldnt it be false since it is at index 0 and we are looking from index 1?

Comment: The third statement is true because the input `"This"` matches the condition `if (findFrom.startsWith(toFind))` and returned `true` immediately.